# How to determine which device is being used for the display

Tags: raspbian, ubuntu

I have a Pi4 running Raspbian OS with an LCD touchscreen display attached. I am not using X so no desktop is shown. The display appears as /dev/fb0 and I want to use this in a kiosk manner (with code that I am writing).

When the Pi boots, it outputs everything to the LCD display, including the console log-in prompt with a flashing cursor. My code then launches as a service and does its stuff.

I need to get rid of the flashing cursor. I know I can do this by adding "tput civis" to ~/.bashrc but doing this means that I have no cursor when I ssh into the Pi. I can get the cursor back for the ssh session by using "tput normal" but it is a pain having to do this every time.

I was thinking that I should only run the "tput civis" command if the output device is the LCD display rather than an ssh session. But how can I determine that, such that I can add a test around the tput command in ~/.bashrc? Or is there another way?

Comment: Have you considered writing a script to make the change when logging in via SSH?

Comment: How would I know it was via ssh rather than the boot console?

Comment: When you SSH into the pi you probably don't log in as root, do you? And so you could just add something to `~/.bashrc` of the user you use for ssh.

Comment: This should help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217270/change-ps1-color-when-connected-to-other-host-via-ssh

Comment: @SteveRobillard, Many thanks, that's solved it